# Why doesn't my linux hyper-v guest display its ipaddress in hyper-v manager

Tags: linux, hyper-v

I'm running Windows 8.1 Enterprise edition using the built-in Hyper-v manager.
I can run linux guests no problem.  However in the manager it wont display the ipaddress.  Windows vm guests do display.

I'm not using the "Legacy Network Adapter".   In the picture below I'm running:

```
~$ cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 8 \n \l

$ cat /etc/debian_version
8.2
```

[image: hyper-v manager]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The package you want for Debian is called **hyperv-daemons**.

Comment: no idea who down voted you, but that package worked for me

Comment: it's voted down, because it's not a correct answer. It does not answer the question itself.

Comment: @asadmin ??? It solved my issue

Comment: @asadmin:  Jake Oshins' answer already provided the **why**.  My answer provided the information needed to actually **fix the problem**.  Excuse me for being useful.

Comment: upvoted - worked for me, thanks - I did 2 things actually (using Ubuntu) - first I enabled LIS: https://oitibs.com/hyper-v-lis-on-ubuntu-16/ and then installed hyper-V tools: https://technet.microsoft.com/windows-server-docs/compute/hyper-v/supported-ubuntu-virtual-machines-on-hyper-v?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: For CentOS the package is the same name (`yum install hyperv-daemons`). According to https://unix.bris.ac.uk/2015/03/12/linux-vms-on-hyper-v-be-sure-to-install-and-run-hyperv-daemons/, you also need to enable/start the `hypervvssd`/`hypervkvpd`.  I think the latter gives the IP address to Hyper-V.

Answer (score 1):

The code necessary to make that happen isn't part of the Linux kernel.  It's a user-mode component that you need to install through whichever package manager your distro uses.

There really is no such thing as "Linux" once you get outside of the kernel.  There are Centos, Ubuntu, RHEL, SUSE, Android, etc.  Each of those is somewhat different.  The exact means to get what you're looking for depends on which Linux-based OS you're using.

Here, for instance, are the instructions for getting what you want (the "cloud tools" set of packages) with Ubuntu:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531029.aspx

Comment: I dont see anything for Debian.   Does anyone know if the Ubuntu packages backport into Debian wheezy?